# Auto-startup a GUI program as admin for all users on pc

Tags: windows, boot, administrator, windows-11

On my computers I usually go with a limited account for daily usage and with an admin account that I use only for certain tasks, as a way to limit the attack surface in case of issues.

For various reasons I need to launch some programs at startup and those programs require an admin account, but I can't use Task Scheduler since they're GUI programs.

I think I've tried all of the known alternatives that can be found online, but it seems I'm out of luck.

Ideally I'd add a link under `shell:common startup`, but this will show the UAC prompt and disabling it is **not** an option. Of course having the prompt for multiple programs on every startup is not an option either.

What am I supposed to do in this scenario?
I remember that my work laptop had some stuff running as admin at startup and with GUI too but I have no idea on how they did it.

I'm also open to write a Windows service for it if it's a valid way to get past the issue.

Comment: The MS recommended approach to admin capabilities in standard user-space, is to separate the program into a windows service which runs as admin, and uses a gui to connect to that service. that way the gui doesn't require special permissions to operate, and the OS manages the service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a GUI program to start with administrator permissions
without the UAC prompt.

In previous Windows versions this was possible, but was closed off by
Microsoft as a security risk, since it would in effect give the
standard user administrator privileges.

Answer (score -1):

Simple: Just add it as a task and enable "Run with highest privileges" and "Run ony when user is logged on".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).